# Socket connection is established but not receiving data Python

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I am using Fast Api,Celery,Docker to develop a application.Now there are two types of endpoints, one is api endpoint and another is socket endpoint.When i hit to the socket endpoint using the url  "ws://localhost:8000/ws" it's telling connection is open

```
 worker    | INFO:     ('172.18.0.1', 47776) - "WebSocket /ws" [accepted]
 worker    | INFO:     connection open
```

but my method is not printing any data

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
    async def test(websocket:WebSocket):
    print("Accepting connection")
    await websocket.accept()
    print("Websocket accepted")
    while True:
       try:
          data = await websocket.receive_text()
          websocket.send("hollow")
          print(data)
       except:
        pass
        break
```

when I hit the endpoint,It does not print anything in console,but in console it is showing connection is open.

this is another endpoint

```
 @app.get('/api/file/{fileId}')
 async def saveRecord(fileId: str):
    tasks = current_app.tasks.keys()
    print(tasks)
    print("Readddd")
    taskId = save_entry.delay(fileId)
    return {"task_id": taskId}
```

this endpoint return the data but for websocket endpoint I am not getting any data.Below is my docker.compose.yml

```
  worker:
    container_name: worker
    build:
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
    context: .
      command: sh -c "cd api && uvicorn app:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000  & cd ../ & celery -A celery_tasks.app_worker worker -l INFO --pool=solo"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

I only specified the command portion in docker. Now what is issue? why socket endpoint is not triggered?

Comment: Where is the client code -- the Javascript that's doing the sending?

Comment: there is chrome extension maned Smart WebSocket Client,I am triggering the call by that extension.